# Suppressing the EULA dialog the first time AIR 2.0 is run

Tags: apache-flex, air

In AIR 1.5, I accomplished this by putting a 'eulaAccepted' file in Application Data\Adobe\AIR.  This doesn't seem to be working in AIR 2.0.  Has anyone figured out how to suppress the EULA dialog in AIR 2.0.2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that prior to AIR 2.0, an empty eulaAccepted file would suppress the EULA dialog.  In AIR 2.0, an empty file doesn't work.  It has to contain "2".